# rails, a model based on a custom SQL query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Say that i have a table that is a group by on many base tables on my database. 

I can implement a database view and so i can then base a model on it as i would do with a regular, 'physical' table. 

Is it possilbe also to specify the sql query of the view directly in the model, so without creating the view at all?

Comment: What would you do about writes (inserts/updates)?

Comment: I talked about 'group by' table for this very reason: they don't support insert or update since they are a summary of existing data. In such a table a row represents the sum of all the invoices of the year, or the average of the temperatures: you can add an invoice or a temperature reading with those models; this has to be a read only model of course.